# How do I make a browser return to the *last* version of my page when using the back button?

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I have a dynamic web page foo.html. The user can interact with various controls, which modify various parts of the page.

When the user leaves the page and later returns with the browser's back button, the user is returned to the *initial* version of the page. **What do I need to do to make the user return to the *final* version of the page?**

Here's a minimal example to reproduce the issue:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
<button id="btnDo">Do something</button>
<!-- Imagine lots of other controls to dynamically create content here. -->
    
<span id="someContent"></span>
<!-- Imagine lots of other fields showing dynamically created content here. -->

<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Leave</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#btnDo").click(function () { $("#someContent").text(new Date()); });
    });
</script>
```

1. Click on "Do something".
2. Note that the current date and time is displayed.
3. Click on "Leave".
4. Click the browser back button (in the snippet, use the context menu).

Desired result: The date and time created in step 2 should still be shown.
Actual result: The initial version of the page is shown.

Comment: You need to store the dynamic data somehow for the user, so when they load the page again it loads in the data.  I would suggest storing it in a cookie and loading the data via JavaScript from the cookie (databases are a much more common solution, but possibly overkill for this example).

Comment: I suppose you could append a URL parameter in the onClick, and then in your doc.ready you can check if the URL parameter is set, if so, run whatever code you need to get it to the "final state"

Comment: @mhodges: I understand what you are saying, but I don't want to "recreate" the state, since this is almost impossible due to the various interactions the user can make (including AJAX calls, which might return different results when called again, etc.). I just want to restore the exact last version of the page *as it was*. Is that possible?

Comment: @Heinzi I see.. As far as I know, session storage, cookies, or server-side state management are your options

Comment: @Heinzi You may(?) be able to do it with something like React, which can manage state. You can probably persist the state of your components in localstorage/cookies and then load that in on the page load and push the state back into your components. Someone more proficient with React would have to verify that.